# JQuery does not work: uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have placed the following JQuery script in my HTML site header **just to test if it works**:

```
//in the header
<script src="modules/mod_djmenu/assets/js/catimage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//This is inside the script, it does load according to Chrome Developer Tools
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar").hide();
});
```

navbar does not hide and I get the error (in Chrome Developer Tools):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'

Have I placed the script in the wrong place? I use Joomla for my site btw.

Site: [europebathroom.com](http://europebathroom.com)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont see that you have included the jquery files

Comment: Plz take time to mark the accepted answer by clicking the green check sign next to th correct answer for other readers to take the benifit

Comment: Had to wait couple of minutes haha, but did it! Too bad only one green mark can be given .. thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Jquery Library in head section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="modules/mod_djmenu/assets/js/catimage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#navbar").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, amazing how helpful people are here! Sorry for my noobishness, its working now :)!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you havent include jquery in your code. Include the jquery, either by refering online or save it as local.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="modules/mod_djmenu/assets/js/catimage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//This is inside the script, it does load according to Chrome Developer Tools
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, amazing how helpful people are here! Sorry for my noobishness, its working now :)!

Answer (score 0):

Add this below script. before your script as you need to add jquery script before it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```